# How to run upstart service in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, upstart

I have purchased a new HP laptop recently with UBUNTU 18.04. But my ongoing project need "Upstart service". After using my new HP laptop, I am unable to find the "Upstart service" in UBUNTU 18.04. My query is, how can I access "Upstart service" in Ubuntu 18.04 ?

Comment: ubuntu changed to systemd - what service are you using from where ?

Comment: @Panther I need upstart service to start the project (NODEJS). I tried to install upstart in ubuntu but when i run the project its say `upstart: connection refused`

Comment: nodejs does not support Ubuntu 18.04 and you can not run upstart on ubuntu 18.04 as Ubuntu now uses systemd. Either use a supported version of ubuntu or file a bug report with nodejs. See https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions and https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: @Panther  Is it possible to install upstart in ubuntu 16.04 and run the project ? if yes, how to install upstart in ubuntu 16.04 (steps to install and how to check if its installed correctly or not)?
I have installed nodejs,problem is a nodejs project need upstart to run it

Comment: I do not know but the links I gave you state 16.04 is supported and include instructions to install in 16.04

Comment: nodejs is in the repositories - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=nodejs . Install from the repos (on 18.04) and if you have a problem submit a bug report

Comment: @Panther nodejs works fine in ubuntu 16.04. i need upstart service to run a file , if i run that,i get upstart: connection failed.

Comment: As I have said, ubuntu does not use upstart and as far as I know you can not install or use upstart. Again, what are you trying to do ? Your question is unclear. You probably need to write a systemd script which is rather trivial, but without details we can not really advise you. Are you running 18.04 or 16.04 ? If your problem is not with nodejs, what is the problem exactly ?

Comment: you can not run upstart on 16.04 so you will have to go to 14.04 or write a systemd scritp which should be trivial